# Mapping and removing duplicates in Spark Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I have a data set `test.txt`. It contain data like below

```
1::1::3
1::1::2
1::2::2
2::1::5
2::1::4
2::2::2
3::1::1
3::2::2
```

I have created data-frame using the below code.

```scala
case class Rating(userId: Int, movieId: Int, rating: Float)
def parseRating(str: String): Rating = {
val fields = str.split("::")
assert(fields.size == 3)
Rating(fields(0).toInt, fields(1).toInt, fields(2).toFloat)
}

val ratings = spark.read.textFile("C:/Users/cravi/Desktop/test.txt").map(parseRating).toDF()
```

But when I am trying to print the output I am getting below output

```
[1,1,3.0]
[1,1,2.0]
[1,2,2.0]
[2,1,2.0]
[2,1,4.0]
[2,2,2.0]
[3,1,1.0]
[3,2,2.0]
```

But I want to print output like below I.e. removing duplicate combinations and instead of `field(2) value 1.0`.

```
[1,1,1.0]
[1,2,1.0]
[2,1,1.0]
[2,2,1.0]
[3,1,1.0]
[3,2,1.0]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you have created a `dataframe` removing duplicates can be done by call `.dropDuplicates(columnNames)` and populating the third column with `1.0` can be done by using `lit` and `withColumn` functions.

To sum up, simple solution can be done as following

```
val ratings = sc.textFile("C:/Users/cravi/Desktop/test.txt")
    .map(line => line.split("::"))
    .filter(fields => fields.length == 3)
    .map(fields => Rating(fields(0).toInt, fields(1).toInt, 1.0f))
  .toDF().dropDuplicates("userId", "movieId")

ratings.show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+------+-------+------+
|userId|movieId|rating|
+------+-------+------+
|3     |1      |1.0   |
|2     |2      |1.0   |
|1     |2      |1.0   |
|1     |1      |1.0   |
|2     |1      |1.0   |
|3     |2      |1.0   |
+------+-------+------+
```